# How do each on scope for don't return a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, relationship

I have a scope

```
class HistoricRefinancing < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :consult_historic_refin, -> (refinancing_id) {
    HistoricRefinancing.where("refinancing_id = ? ", "#{refinancing_id}")  }
end
```

And I called it here (refinancings_controller.rb):

```
  def cancel_refinancing

    @hist_refin = HistoricRefinancing.consult_historic_refin(params[:refinancing_id])
    @hist_refin.authorization.update_columns(situation: 1)
  end
```

But have two problems, first when I do puts on @hist_refin, return this:

```
-------
  HistoricRefinancing Load (3.1ms)  SELECT "HISTORIC==_REFINANCINGS".* FROM "HISTORIC_REFINANCINGS" WHERE (refinancing_id = '17' )
#<HistoricRefinancing:0x007f616c515cc8>
```

And this error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `authorization' for #<HistoricRefinancing::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f617b1d35d8>:
```

My relationships is correct, authorization has many refinancings, refinancig belongs to authorization, historic refinancing has authorization_origin_id (equivalent authorization_id, but I needed change the name), refinancing_id and authorization_new_id

All I want is change column situation for 1, but only authorizations that refinancings. How do it, please?

---

As the help of you:

```
 def cancel_refinancing

        @hist_refin = HistoricRefinancing.consult_historic_refin(params[:refinancing_id])
       @hist_refin.map{|hr| hr.authorization.update_attributes(situation: 1) }

      end
```

And this error I receive:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass:
```

= (

Comment: FYI you should be using `HistoricRefinancing.where(refinancing_id: refinancing_id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@hist_refin is a collection.  You can't call authorization on a collection, you can only call it on an instance of HistoricRefinancing.  If you want to update each one you can map through them.

```
@hist_refin.map{|hr| hr.update_attributes(situation: 1) }
```

If you only want the first one you can call `@hist_refin.first.authorization.updata_attributes(situation: 1)`

Comment: Error: :UnknownAttributeError - unknown attribute 'situation' for HistoricRefinancing.: I need do a join in my scope? Join with table Authorization?

Comment: NoMethodError - undefined method `update_all' for 20:Fixnum: return this error for me =/

Comment: class HistoricRefinancing < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :consult_historic_refin, -> (refinancing_id) {
    HistoricRefinancing.where("refinancing_id = ? ", "#{refinancing_id}").includes(:authorization)  }
end

Comment: so, now have this error NoMethodError - undefined method `update_all' for 20:Fixnum: ever one worse than the other (update_all, updates_attributes, all...)

Comment: where are you calling update_all?  I don't see that in your code.  Perhaps create a new question to get this sorted as it seems out of scope of your original question.

Comment: I just substitute update_attibutes for update_all, but the error is same:  NoMethodError - undefined method `update_attributes' for 20:Fixnum:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111255/discussion-between-elton-santos-and-ruby-newbie).